# PDO update in a loop not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

Why this simple update fail every times and give me the same times in each updated row?
If I try to print `$passo` in the loop the result is correct!
And yes, ArrivalTime and ArrivalTime2 contains the same value...

```
$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=travelplanner3',
             'xxxxx', 'xxxxxx', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8mb4", PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$insert=$db->prepare("UPDATE
                                       vuote_stop_lazio2
                                      SET arrival_time= :arrivalTime,
                                       departure_time=:arrivalTime2
                                       WHERE trip_id= :idTrip
                                       AND arrivaL_time=0");
                $arrivalTime= null ;
                $arrivalTime2= null ;
                $stoppe=null;

                $insert->bindParam(':arrivalTime',$arrivalTime);
                $insert->bindParam(':arrivalTime2',$arrivalTime2);
                $insert->bindParam(':idTrip',$stoppe);        

            foreach( $arrayIncrementi as $passo )
            {
                $arrivalTime = $passo;
                $arrivalTime2=$passo;
                $stoppe=$stop['trip_id'];
                $insert->execute();
            }
```

Comment: You think changing the variables values and executing without binding the variables again will give you your intended result ? Update with same values != update fails every time.

Comment: What does http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php show before the execute?

Comment: one out many row... smell like some errors happen `SQL: [301] UPDATE vuote_stop_lazio2 SET arrival_time= :arrivalTime, departure_time=:arrivalTime2 WHERE trip_id= :idTrip AND arrivaL_time=0 Params: 3 Key: Name: [12] :arrivalTime paramno=-1 name=[12] ":arrivalTime" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [13] :arrivalTime2 paramno=-1 name=[13] ":arrivalTime2" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [7] :idTrip paramno=-1 name=[7] ":idTrip" is_param=1 param_type=2 13:30:04`

Comment: `$stop['trip_id']` contains the correct id value and `$passo` is correct too;

Comment: "give me the same times in each updated row" -- Is this null times? The first value of `$arrayIncrementi` ? The last value of `$arrayIncrementi` ?

Comment: no all the $passo from $arrayIncrementi it seems to be correct:` 0=> 13:28:01
1=> 13:28:02
2=> 13:28:03
3=> 13:28:04
4=> 13:28:05
5=> 13:28:06`

Comment: if I run the code without the `$insert->execute();`  the things is correctly evaluated but is I uncomment this line even the array is wrong!

Comment: same bad result :( with this: `$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "travelplanner3");

            $stoppe=$stop['trip_id'];
            $passo=0;

            for( $i=0; $i<count($arrayIncrementi); $i++){
                $passo=$arrayIncrementi[$i];
                $link->query(" UPDATE  vuote_stop_lazio2
                                  SET arrival_time= '$passo',
                                   departure_time='$passo'
                                   WHERE trip_id= '$stoppe'
                                   AND arrivaL_time=0");
            }`